# Is "arts" (a subject in schools) a singular noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, academia

When used as subject, is the word *arts* considered a singular noun or a
plural one?

1. **Art** is my favorite class at school this term.
2. **Arts** is<sup>?</sup> my favorite class at school this term.

Why can’t we just say we’re taking or studying *art* in school? Why do we
ever say *arts* as though it were plural but then use a singular verb
anyway?

Does the answer vary by locality, such as in the United Kindom or Ireland,
Australia or New Zealand, the United States or Canada, India or Singapore,
or South Africa?

Comment: In India the often used style is 'arts'. We say, arts and science. It is like maths in India unlike math in many other countries. As a discipline arts is considered singular, like maths is difficult; arts is interesting; linguistics is a science - these are not used as singular. // Sometimes 'art' is used a little differently, like "He knows the art of swindling." (Here, it is not 'arts', but art.)

Comment: Subjects in educational systems have local names with local grammars. In the USA, _mathematics_ is singular, and so is its abbreviation, _math_; *_maths_ does not occur in American English. _Arts_ is another frequent word in names, as is _Art_, which is always singular. _Arts_, however, can swing either way -- if it's part of a name it can be either singular of plural: _The Art School; College of Arts and Sciences; Arts, Science, and Technology,_ etc.

Comment: The term arts is not used on its own as a subject in school. Fine Arts, yes, And other x arts, but not just art. tchrist is removing my comment, which is germane to the question. Mine is just as germane as John Lawler's comment.

Comment: *My favorite class**es** are all in the Arts. Of those, Art is my number one.* Of course you could have a class entitled "The Arts in U.S. Education"

Answer (score 3):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Subjects in educational systems have local names with local grammars. In the USA, *mathematics* is singular, and so is its abbreviation, *math*; **maths* does not occur in American English. *Arts* is another frequent word in names, as is *Art*, which is always singular. *Arts*, however, can swing either way -- if it's part of a name it can be either singular or plural: *The Art School; College of Arts and Sciences; Arts, Science, and Technology,* etc.

Comment: @Lambie Industrial Arts was pretty much an obligatory class for boys when I was a lad.

Comment: @tchrist I thought you majored in the Dark Arts.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking:
The ideas below:
"Art is my favorite class at school this term.
Arts is? my favorite class at school this term." [not a standard expression]

work like this:

**If you study art in school**, you will most likely be doing painting and drawing (sketching) and maybe some sculpture. You might also study art in the sense of art history. And take a course in the history of art: Introduction to Art History

**The arts are what interest me**. [as opposed to the sciences]
As in fine arts, theater, film.

The use of the plural is used in many formal titles:
Bachelor in Fine Arts
The School of Fine Arts

Comment: Just to highlight something that I see covered only in this answer: Yes, there can be regional differences that determine whether you use singular or plural. But you can also change the meaning, even within a regional usage, by switching the number.

Comment: Andy, I doubt that the plural and singular are used differently by region. If by region, you mean things like Canada, the UK, Australia, etc.  Art is art and the arts are the arts.

Comment: There's a comment on the original question asserting that in India is often "arts," like the UK use of "maths." I can't confirm, especially since they also mention the phrase "arts and sciences," whether they mean that a class restricted to visual art would be referred to as "arts."